# Trying to establish remote debug with visual studio running inside vmpalyer

Tags: debugging, vmware, remote-desktop

i have this configuration

a visual studio running inside virtual machine. the host machine has xp on it and so does the virtual machine.

i have to run remote debug on the third machine which is connected to the host machine.

i m currently facing this problem

i m not able to ping my virtual machine from my host machine, however reverse is possible. how to resolve that? both my machine are on same workgroup (not domain, arent they both same?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting with Bridged Mode, not NAT or host-only mode in VMWare?